# Strongly typed Dataset, Coumn DBNull

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a stored procedure that works and returns some columns including "Column_A".

I am able to get Column_A value in a row when I execute Stored Procudure within SQL Manageemnt Tools.

When I try to preview the same row within a typed dataset Column_A is always null.

Any idea What could be wrong ?

Comment: Where is your ADO code ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you Ali, it's just a strongly typed dataset and I am using "Preview" function to see the returned data

Comment: Preview function ? are you talking about SSRS reporting Service ?

Comment: This is what I am talking about Ali, http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/37105/  , it's just an example

Answer (score 1):

Strongly-typed dataset rules of engagement.

```
The column name must be EXACT.  

The data-type should match.

The column_names order should match.  Which also means the total number of columns in the result query should equal the number of columns in the datatable definition.
```

Aka, if you have

```
Select e.LastName, e.FirstName, e.SSN from dbo.Employee
```

your strong dataset should be

```
LastName (string)
FirstName (string)
SSN (string)
```

It cannot be a deviation like any of the below:

```
Last_Name (string)
FName (string)
SSNumber (string)
```

If your strong-dataset-table__column does not allow "nulls", then you must code a dummy-value in the procedure.

example:

```
Select e.LastName, e.FirstName, IsNull(e.SSN, '') as SSN from dbo.Employee
```

Every time I have one of these issues, I always find I violated one of these mini rules.

Comment: +1, It seems like problem with order of columns, do you know how can I move them around, as it doesn't let me just straight away, maybe time to create a new dataset ? my dataset consists of 3 stored procedures, so maybe I need to change all of them into same order

Comment: If you're SUPER CAREFUL, you can open the xsd in notepad and move them around.  Make a backup before you edit.  (and close your solution in visual studio before you do this)

Comment: Just realized, I have got another problem, 3 of stored procedure are using same dataset but returning different columns back, :-(

Comment: "total number of columns in the result query should equal the number of columns in the datatable definition."  not agreed with this one, as it was working for me with different numbers of columns within a dataset, can you provide a reference please

Comment: No reference, just my personal best practice.  Maybe your return procedure can have missing columns on the end.  Aka, the data-set-table is "bigger".  Your issue of reusing the same dataset with different columns........that's a big headache waiting to happen, IMHO.

Comment: Any many many headaches of figuring out why a strongly-typed dataset won't load.

Comment: Saddly it's not about column order, I changed order of other columns and they still work :/, column name seems fine as well, thanks, I will keep looking

Comment: Column ordering and numbering doesn't matter, as long as you map it to the right column :)

Comment: "Technically possible" is in a different category than "keep your sanity".  After you've debugged 10 of these strong-dataset issues, you'll start insisting on consistency between order and names and etc, etc.  Well, that's my humble opinion.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Because I added the column myself, "Source" property of DataColumn was not set, so setting it or in other words mapping it to right column, fixed the issue.